# Excel -- Comparing 2 lists with several columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sorting, cleaning

I have 2 lists with several columns. Each list has 5 columns, and 4/5 columns will have different values from both lists, but the remaining column is for dates. Both lists' 'Dates' Column are of different length, so some dates exist in one list that don't exist in the other. I need to be able to scan the column of dates in both lists and extract the rows associated with matching dates into another list.

```
List 1 
  Date            O       H       L      LP
 10/2/16 17:42  -0.58   -0.58   -0.58   -0.58 
 10/2/16 17:46  -0.58   -0.58   -0.58   -0.58 
 10/2/16 17:47  -0.58   -0.58   -0.58   -0.58 

List 2
 Date              O      H       L      LP 
10/2/16 17:42   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57 
10/2/16 17:46   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57 
10/2/16 17:47   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57 
10/2/16 17:49   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57 
10/2/16 17:50   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57 
10/2/16 17:55   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57   -0.57
```

Am not sure if it the lists can be viewed properly. But basically its 2 lists - each list has 5 columns - Date, O, H, L, LP. The latter 4 columns (O, H, L, LP) are irrelevant. The dates from both lists need to be matched and the associated rows for each matched date needs to be extracted to a third list.

Comment: Give an example of the source data and the desired result for it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lxSsJ0U89mxBI0-WaW6_VRe5ntKVBYcb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Above google doc link is example of data. Desired result would be a third list inclusive of all rows of data associated with matching Date's of both lists.

Comment: Instead of linking to an off-site download, can you add more description to your post? I (and I'm sure others) are hesitant to download random files from the Internet, especially if/when macros may be involved.

Comment: @Riyer - Please don't add information in comments, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1365201/edit) instead. It will make things a lot easier for everyone

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad understood

Comment: Do you have a list of all the dates? If yes, a `VLOOKUP` might do the job

Comment: Data contains duplicate values and `VLOOKUP` will only return the first match.  It can work in conjunction with other formulas but will give inaccurate results is used alone.  I'd like to know if there are restrictions against helper columns, new sheets, or using VBA.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious there are no restrictions. Needs to be done in any way possible. And, after finding duplicate dates, will need to match those dates with other 4 columns of data from both lists.

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to suggest three steps solution:**

1. *Write this Formula in Cell `H2` & fill it 
    down.*

   `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$9,0)),"",E2)`

**Note:** *Formula will extract Duplicate Dates 
  comparing both Tables.*

[image]

2. *Select entire Data Range(A1:H9) & Apply 
   **Auto filter**, then check the **Year** to 
    execute Filter.*
3. *Finally **Copy & Paste** Filtered Record 
    where you need them.*

Comment: @Riyer,, glad to help you keep asking ☺